# Echo error data using str_replace function

Tags: str-replace

I have a problem to replace a certain format with a symbol inside the number. I use below the coding to replace, but not work for me to replace the symbol, the result won't come out.

```html
$try = "100-1-1 abc/bbb";
$try_1 = "100-1-1-16 John/James";

echo(replaceHyphen($try));
echo(replaceHyphen($try_1));

<script>
function replaceHyphen($str) {
    $i = -1;
    for($i=0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        if($str[$i] == "-") break;
    }
    for($i++; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        if($str[$i] == "-") $str[$i] = '/';
        if($str[$i] == " ") break;
    }
    return $str;
}
</script>
```

I want the expected result like below:

```html
100-1/1 abc/bbb
100-/1/16 John/James
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: It is php language

Comment: I don't think anyone familiar with php is going to find your Question without the tag on it. But I also think you should add what the result of this code is, not just what you expect it to be.